# Change string Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem writing code in Python and BS4.

Assuming have the next paragraph:

```
<p id="paragraph">
Here is the paragraph <a href="/" id="url">Here an url</a> the paragraph continues.
</p>
```

I take the id and use `replace_with` to replace the string (in P and A tag). But in this case, results in this:

```
Here is the paragraph the paragraph continues. Here an url
```

The structure is not respected. What is the correct method?

Add some code:

```
page = open('file.html')
soupPage = BeautifulSoup(page)
findId = soupPage.find(id='nameOfId')
findId.replace_with('NewString')
```

Comment: Could you include your code as well please?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes, I edit the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = open('file.html')
soupPage = BeautifulSoup(page)
findId = soupPage.find(id='url')
findId.contents[0].replace_with('NewString')
print soupPage
```

prints:

```
<html><body><p id="paragraph">
Here is the paragraph <a href="/" id="url">NewString</a> the paragraph continues.
</p></body></html>
```

Hope it's what you wanted.